# Match Chinese character in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, utf-8

I know this question has been asked before.  I did check all the previous answers but still could not solve my problem.  Please pardon me for the apparently duplicate question.

I'm writing a perl program to process text file in Chinese. I want to recognize the Chinese text but exclude all other lines such as English or other language and urls. I use "`use utf8`" and "`$line =~ /(\p{Han}+)/`" but it does nothing.  If I use "`use utf8`" and "`$line =~ /信息/`", it does nothing.  If I don't use "`use utf8`", "`$line =~ /信息/`" can work but not "`$line =~ /(\p{Han}+)/`".  I check text file encoding with: file -bi input.txt, it shows: "`text/plain; charset=utf-8`".  The following is the code:

```
$|=1;
use strict;
use utf8;

my $in = $ARGV[0];

sub main {

    open(IN, "$in") or die "can't open $in\n";

    while (my $line=<IN>) {
        chomp($line);

        if ($line =~ /(\p{Han}+)/ ) { 
        print "chinese: $line\n";
        }

        if ($line =~ /信息/) {
           print "$line\n";
        }

    } # end while

   close(IN); 
}
```

Thank you in advance for  any help and advice!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to open the file as UTF-8:

```
open IN, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $in or die "can't open $in\n";
```

Otherwise it's read as a byte string, which isn't what you want.

Comment: This actually did produce correct output, but, with a lot of lines like this:
Wide character in print at test.pl line 13, <IN> line 4.

Comment: Fixed it by adding:
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
Thanks a lot!  The whole thing works now!

Comment: It‘s great. Help me a lot.

Answer (score -2):

You must use the u modifier if you want that the regex engine treats your string as an unicode string:

```
/(\p{Han}+)/u
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.  I tried but it still does nothing.

Comment: See [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Character-set-modifiers). If the regex or the string are in utf8-format, or if the pattern mentions unicode features (`\p`, `\N{}`, high code points), unicode semantics are chosen. The `/u` is useful to make this explicit, but does not change anything in *this* case. The charset modifiers are useful to indicate how `\w`, `\d` and `/i` modifier should work (also: related charcters and ligatures).